# R - Remove rows with same values AND rows with same combinations of values

Tags: r, duplicates, unique

I have some data that looks like this:

```
Row  From   To      Value
1    MA1007 MA1007  2
2    MA1007 MA2801  1
3    MA2801 MA1017  1
4    MA1051 MA2066  2
5    MA1051 MA2059  1
6    MA2066 MA1051  2
7    MA2066 MA2066  1
```

I want to remove all rows where the values are the same in the `From` and `To` columns. In the example above, that means rows 1 and 7 would be removed. However, I also want to remove any rows where the combination of values in the `From` and `To` column appear more than once (retaining just one instance of that row). For example, row 2 or 3 would be removed (they both contain the same combination of "MA" codes albeit in different columns). Either row 4 or 6 would also be removed. In case it makes any difference, the `Value` column will also have the same value for a specific combination. E.g. rows 2 and 3 have the same value, as do rows 4 and 6.

Here's how the final data should look:

```
Row  From   To      Value
2    MA1007 MA2801  1
4    MA1051 MA2066  2
5    MA1051 MA2059  1
```

Any thoughts on how I should approach this? Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `subset` to create an expression where the 'From' values are not equal (`!=`) to 'To' and (`&`) where it is not (`!`) `duplicated` for 'From', 'To', after `sort`ing by row with `pmin/pmax`

```
subset(df1, From != To & !duplicated(cbind(pmin(From, To), pmax(From, To))))
```

-output

```
 Row   From     To Value
2   2 MA1017 MA2801     1
4   4 MA1051 MA2066     2
5   5 MA1051 MA2059     1
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Row = 1:7, From = c("MA1007", "MA1017", "MA2801", 
"MA1051", "MA1051", "MA2066", "MA2066"), To = c("MA1007", "MA2801", 
"MA1017", "MA2066", "MA2059", "MA1051", "MA2066"), Value = c(2L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-7L))
```

Comment: Works perfectly. Thanks for providing another solution :)

Comment: Brilliant way. I think this is more straightforward than using `igraph`. Upvoted!

Answer (score 0):

An `igraph` option using `simplify` + `graph_from_data_frame` + `get.data.frame`

```
merge(
    setNames(get.data.frame(
        simplify(
            graph_from_data_frame(df[-1], directed = FALSE),
            edge.attr.comb = "mean"
        )
    ), names(df)[-1]),
    df
)
```

gives

```
    From     To Value Row
1 MA1017 MA2801     1   2
2 MA1051 MA2059     1   5
3 MA1051 MA2066     2   4
```